# Can i use the input or open function with send_keys function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like the `password.send_keys` function open up a text file and read it
(like trying all different password from text file), how can I link it or use it with `selenium`?

```py
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")))
    
username.clear()
password.clear()
name = "myusername"
username.send_keys(name)
    
password.send_keys(passwords)
with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python folder/python projects/passlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    passwords = data.split('\n')
      
sleep(2)
log_in = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can open the file using this:

```
with open('path/to/my/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    passwords = data.split('\n')
```

Now you can use your passwords variable (which is a list) to send the keys for example with a loop